# How to detect touch except the falling bodies from top in cocos2d-x ios game using c++

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

In my game there are certain zombies coming from top of the screen.I have stored all zombies sprites in an CCArray.Then using foreach loop I am making them falling down.
I just want to perform combo.It means that whenever I kill a zombie on tap, the combo_counter increases.
On killing two consecutive zombies the combo_counter goes to 2 but if I tap at any other location on the screen the combo_counter should go to 0.

So my problem is how to detect whether I have not tapped a zombie and tapped anyother place on the screen.I am attaching my code also  of cctouchbegan method

zombies is a CCArray where all zombie sprites are stored

```
void Level1::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)(pTouch->anyObject());
CCPoint location = touch->getLocationInView();
location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);

CCObject* touchedzombie;

CCARRAY_FOREACH(zombies, touchedzombie)
{


    if(!((CCSprite*) touchedzombie)->isVisible())
        continue;
    //

    if(((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)==zombies->objectAtIndex(0))
    {

        //   if((CCSprite*(touchedzombie)==zombies-))
        if(touchedzombie!=NULL&&((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
        {

            this->setScoreonGame();
            combo_counter++;
            CCString *comboString=CCString::createWithFormat("comboX %d",combo_counter);

            zombies_left--;
            CCLOG("left = %d",zombies_left);
            CCSize tt=((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)->getContentSize();
            CCPoint pos_of_sprite=((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)->getPosition();
            int rand_die1=Level1::random1();
            CCString *str = CCString::createWithFormat("z2%d.png", rand_die1);
            changedSprite = CCSprite::create(str->getCString());
            CCLOG("Inside index 0");

            ((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)->setVisible(false);

            changedSprite->setPositionX(pos_of_sprite.x);
            changedSprite->setPositionY(pos_of_sprite.y);
            changedSprite->setScaleX(Utils::getScaleX());
            changedSprite->setScaleY(Utils::getScaleY());
            this->addChild(changedSprite);


            combo=CCLabelTTF::create(comboString->getCString(), "HoboStd", 50);
            combo->setColor(ccRED);
            combo->setPosition((ccp(changedSprite->getContentSize().width*0.50,changedSprite->getContentSize().height*1.05)));
            changedSprite->addChild(combo,40);



            this->runAction(CCSequence::create(delayAction,
                                               callSelectorAction,
                                               NULL));


            this->removeChild( ((CCSprite*)touchedzombie),true);
            this->Level1::reloadZombies();
            //  touchedzombie=NULL;

        }






    }





    if(((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)==zombies->objectAtIndex(3))
    {


        //   if((CCSprite*(touchedzombie)==zombies-))
        if(touchedzombie!=NULL&&((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
        {
         //    iftouched++;
            this->setScoreonGame();
            combo_counter++;
            CCString *comboString=CCString::createWithFormat("comboX %d",combo_counter);

            zombies_left--;
            CCLOG("left = %d",zombies_left);
            CCSize tt=((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)->getContentSize();
            CCPoint pos_of_sprite=((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)->getPosition();
            int rand_die1=Level1::random1();
            CCString *str = CCString::createWithFormat("z2%d.png", rand_die1);
            changedSprite3 = CCSprite::create(str->getCString());
            //  CCLOG("%s",str->getCString());


            //  CCLOG("Sprite Toucheddd");
            CCLOG("Inside index 4");
            // CCLog("width= %f  height =%f",tt.width,tt.height);
            // CCLog("x location =%f  y location =%f",location.x,location.y);
            //  CCLog("Positon of Sprite X=%f  Y=%f",pos_of_sprite.x,pos_of_sprite.y);

            ((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)->setVisible(false);

            changedSprite3->setPositionX(pos_of_sprite.x);
            changedSprite3->setPositionY(pos_of_sprite.y);
            changedSprite3->setScaleX(Utils::getScaleX());
            changedSprite3->setScaleY(Utils::getScaleY());
            this->addChild(changedSprite3);

            combo=CCLabelTTF::create(comboString->getCString(), "HoboStd", 50);
            combo->setColor(ccRED);
            combo->setPosition((ccp(changedSprite3->getContentSize().width*0.50,changedSprite3->getContentSize().height*1.05)));
            changedSprite3->addChild(combo,40);


            this->runAction(CCSequence::create(delayAction,
                                               callSelectorAction3,
                                               NULL));

            this->removeChild( ((CCSprite*)touchedzombie),true);
            this->Level1::reloadZombies();
            touchedzombie=NULL;
        }
        //..upto 9 indexes...      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not neccesary to do this checks : `if(((CCSprite*)touchedzombie)==zombies->objectAtIndex(0))`

How `CCARRAY_FOREACH` works, is it takes each object from the provided `CCArray` and assigns it to your `touchedZombie` variable - this means that if there are 10 elements in the array, this code will be run 10 times (exactly!). This means that with the first run, you will fall into the first `if` check (the one with `objectAtIndex(0)`, with the second it will fall into the `if` check with `objectAtIndex(1)`. Removing this if's not will not only speed up your function, but also tidy it up.

This would save you a lot of space, plus if you wanted to change something you would only have to do it in one place, which is safer.

Ok, to the problem at hand :

I see two solutions to this :

1. Leaving your code : you should move the combo code from the `if` blocks, and replace it with a flag. This flag should be set to `false` at the beginning of `ccToucheBegan`, and if you you detect a touch on a zombie, set it to `true`. Then after the `CCARRAY_FOREACH` block, this flag will tell you if there was a tap on a zombie or not. Change your combo accordingly.
2. Changing your code : You could also make the zombies CCMenuItemImages - this way they would have a different callback function than the rest of the screen. So whenever the `ccTouchBegan` method would be fired, you will know that it wasn't a zombie that was touched.

I hope everything is clear, if not - let me know.